# Toolbar back button wont do anything

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar

My app switches from MainActivity to ChatActivity when user presses a button. Problem is the back button on my toolbar won't do anything, while the default back button on UI works. Here's what I've tried:

1. Set these 2 options to true

   supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
   supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
2. Making MainActivity the parent of ChatActivity:

`<activity android:name=".ChatActivity" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />`

The compiles and runs without any errors. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
            finish()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

This works fine add the above code in your activity